# Migrate FormsAuthentication to .NET5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

We have an ASP.NET MVC project running on .NET Framework 4.6.1, we use Forms authentication with cookies. We need to migrate this project to .NET 5.0, however Forms authentication is no longer supported.

What would be the best approach/course of action in order to introduce an authentication process that could fit with this migration?

Answer (score 3):

We have used this project https://github.com/synercoder/FormsAuthentication for ASP.NET Core 3.1 and it allows us to seamlessly share cookies of old ASP.NET’s Forms Authentication. You can certainly use it on .net 5 onwards.

Comment: Also works for .net 8.0!